# Deleting duplicates from multiple tables using MapInfo

Tags: mapinfo, mapbasic

Using the delete duplicates tool is there a way in Mapbasic to have it run through a large number of tables, or do you have to manually select each table and run the tool?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the MapBasic source code for the Delete Duplicates tool in your MapBasic installations folder: ..\Samples\MAPBASIC\DeleteDuplicates

With this you can modify the code to loop thru all open tables or modify the dialog to let the user pick more than one table.